# primary key of new row automatically goes to 2nd table where it's a foreign key in a new row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This is my 1st table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Booking_Date] 
(
    [Book_ID]            INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Book_Checkin_Date]  DATETIME NULL,
    [Book_Checkout_date] DATETIME NULL,
    [Adults]             INT      NULL,
    [Children]           INT      NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Booking_Date] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Book_ID] ASC)
);
```

And this is my 2nd table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Room_Detail] 
(
    [R_D_ID]     INT   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Cust_ID]    INT   NULL,
    [Book_ID]    INT   NULL,
    [Room_ID]    INT   NULL,
    [Room_Price] MONEY NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([R_D_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Room_Detail_Customer] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([Cust_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Cust_ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Room_Detail_Booking_Date] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([Book_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Booking_Date] ([Book_ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Room_Detail_Room] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([Room_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Room] ([Room_ID])
);
```

When I insert data into my 1st table a with booking date, then primary key of that data automatically is inserted into the 2nd table that is Room Detail in the `Book_ID` column

Comment: Are you looking for a solution inside SQL Server (using triggers)? Or something else? What about the other columns in `Room_Detail` - should they all be left `NULL` when inserting your new `Booking_Date.Book_ID` into `Room_Detail`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in T-SQL / SQL Server, you can use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the `Booking_Date` table - something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsertBookingDate
ON dbo.Booking_Date
AFTER INSERT
AS
    -- for each row newly inserted into "Booking_Date",
    -- insert a new (empty) row into "Room_Detail"
    INSERT INTO dbo.Room_Detail(Book_ID)
        SELECT i.Book_ID
        FROM Inserted i
```

So every time you insert one or multiple row(s) into `Booking_Date`, a new (more or less empty) row will be inserted into `Room_Detail` for each of those new rows inserted. Since you don't have any other information available, you can *only* set the `Book_ID` column of `Room_Detail` in the trigger - the other columns will have to somehow be specified / filled later